# Publish simple html + Kendo UI app as ipad application

Tags: ipad, kendo-ui, publish

I am creating a new html application using kendo ui. It is calling the web services to get the data and the ui is rendered using Kendo UI. I want this app to be published as ios app.

Is it possible to publish this app directly as a ipad / iphone app ?

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this information can be useful to someone who is trying to achieve the same thing.

[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_in) is the online tool , that allows you to publish html apps as ios , android or windows applications.

All you need is js , css and html pages of your applications with a valid and well formatted config.xml file. You can upload the zip file with all these files and this portal will build the apps for all 3 platforms and will allow you to download the .ipa, .apk and .xap files.

Thanks.